# Get a column that is not specified in group-by clause

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, greatest-n-per-group

Need to retrieve a column from a group-by query, and this column is not part of the group-by clause.

I have a table that receives telemetries from equipments:

COLUMNS:

- transmission_tag varchar -- this is kind of a transmission package identifier
- equipment_id int
- measurement int   -- the value measured
- uts int    -- the timestamp 'unixtime' of the measurement

Then I need to get the most recent measurement from every equipment:

```
SELECT equipment_id, max(uts)
FROM telemetry
GROUP BY equipment_id
-- works OK and quick, the table has ~100mi registers and has index on (equipment_id, uts)
```

The question is that I need to get the "transmission_tag" related to this registers.

I tried with "WHERE EXISTS" / "WITH auxquery (...) SELECT...", but I was not able to solve this problem.

The example below retrieves exactly what I need (for testing purposes), but it is really dumb. In the real world database, it takes 1 hour to run (it does a sequential scan of all registers).

```
SELECT transmission_tag
FROM telemetry
WHERE CAST(equipment_id as VARCHAR) || '_' || CAST(uts as VARCHAR) IN
 (SELECT CAST(equipment_id as VARCHAR) || '_' || CAST(max(uts) as VARCHAR)
  FROM telemetry
  GROUP BY equipment_id)
```

The rows in the table are unique, there is only one row with (equipment_id, uts).

In case the answer is db specific, I'm using Postgres.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `inner join` to join your dataset with the table then get **transmission_tag** :

```
SELECT t.equipment_id, s.max_uts, t.transmission_tag
FROM telemetry t
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT equipment_id, max(uts) AS max_uts
  FROM telemetry
  GROUP BY equipment_id
) as s on s.equipment_id = t.equipment_id and s.max_uts = t.uts
```

Comment: Your answer with INNER JOIN had a great performance, only took 8 seconds to run. Query plan shows it uses index scan and hashaggregate (instead of sequential scan when using DISTINCT ON). Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> I need to get the most recent measurement from every equipment [...] The question is that I need to get the `transmission_tag` related to this registers.

You want to *filter* the table, not aggregate it. In Postgres, I would recommend [`distinct on`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html), which does exactly what you ask for:

> `SELECT DISTINCT ON ( expression [, ...] )` keeps only the first row of each set of rows

This gives you the entire latest row of each equipment:

```
select distinct on (equipment_id) t.*
from telemetry t
order by equipment_id, uts desc
```

Comment: Thanks. Your answer returns the right rows, but it does a sequential scan, and this table is too big, took about 20 min to run. The other answer which uses INNER JOIN took 8 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `distinct on` clause such;

```
select distinct on (equipment_id)
    equipment_id, 
    transmission_tag,
    uts
  from telemetry
  order by equipment_id, uts desc;
```

The query says order by `equipment_id, uts desc` then get first row for each distinct `equipment_id`. Next, you have your row and you can get any field value from that row.

Comment: Thanks. Your answer returns the right rows, but it does a sequential scan, and this table is too big, took about 20 min to run. The other answer which uses INNER JOIN took 8 seconds.

Comment: @pzn try to create index with `create index on telemetry(equipment_id, uts desc)`

Comment: This index already existed